# How can I view CruiseControl.Net logs in real time?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I use CruiseControl.Net for continuous integration and I would like to read the log output of the current project in real time.  For example, if it is running a compile command, I want to be able to see all the compile output so far.  I can see where the log files are stored but it looks like they are only created once the project finishes.  Is there any way to get the output in real time?

Answer (score 1):

The CCTray app will allow you to see a snapshot of the last 5 or so lines of output of any command on a regular interval.

It's not a live update as that would be too resource intensive, as would be a full output of the log to-date.

Unless you write something to capture and store the snapshots you're out of luck. Doing this also presents to possibility of missing messages that appear between snapshots, so it would not be entirely reliable. It would however give you a slightly better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Actually part of the problem is that the snapshot doesn't appear to show the output of certain commands.  Sometimes when I look at it I just see the command that is being run but not the output from that command.

Answer (score 1):

You can run ccnet.exe as a command line application instead of running ccservice as a Windows service. It will output to the terminal as it runs. It's useful for debugging.

Comment: That's a good point.  We use the service version because (I think) that allows us to set up the website that shows server status.  But its possible some kind of hybrid approach could work.